# Why is my node asynchronous firestore code running in an unexpected order?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, promise

I'm trying to write a function that will query my firestore database. This resulting document returned will have a field called "eventHash". This is a reference to another document in Firestore. I then fetch that document and want to inject that retreived document into the originally retreived document. Then, I push the modified doucment to the response and return. The problem is, the res.send() at the bottom is executing before all the documents are pushed onto the response. Why is this happening?

I tried the following.

```
eventsRouter.get("/", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const response: DocumentData[] = [];
  await getDocs(collection(db, "eventGeoHashes"))
    .then((docs) => {
      docs.forEach(async (doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        if (data.hasOwnProperty("eventHash")) {
          const eventRef: DocumentReference = data.eventHash;
          await getDoc(eventRef).then((event) => {
            data.event = event.data();
          });
        }
        response.push(data);
      });
    })
    .then(() => res.send(response));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you don't wait for all the results you've got in `forEach`.

You can use `map` instead of `forEach` to gather all the promises the internal function returned, and use `Promise.all` to wait for all the promises being resolved.

```
.then((docs) => {
  return Promise.all(docs.map(async (doc) => {
    const data = doc.data();
    if (data.hasOwnProperty("eventHash")) {
      const eventRef: DocumentReference = data.eventHash;
      await getDoc(eventRef).then((event) => {
        data.event = event.data();
      });
     }
    response.push(data);
  }));
})
```

Actually, you don't need to prepare `response` beforehand because you can get a result of each iteration with `map`. Finally, it's better to always use `async/await` or always use promises, but not mix them.

```
eventsRouter.get("/", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const docs = await getDocs(collection(db, "eventGeoHashes"));
  const response = await Promise.all(docs.map(async (doc) => {
    const data = doc.data();
    if (data.hasOwnProperty("eventHash")) {
      const eventRef: DocumentReference = data.eventHash;
      const event = await getDoc(eventRef);
      data.event = event.data();
    }
    return data;
  }));
  res.send(response);
});
```